# TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I am trying to use the Spacy library again for my NPL task. somedays back it was working totally fine with spacy.load("en_core_web_sm"). I thought of using medium instead of small, but now nothing is working. I play around with spacy versions from the latest (3.6.1) to older (3.2.0). I am able to install SpaCy 3.2.0 and can download (!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md) medium pipeline too, however getting the "**TypeError**" error while loading. ( I tried for both small & medium, and got the same error). I will appreciate your help. Thanks in Advance!!

```
!pip install spacy==3.2.0
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
import spacy
from pydantic import BaseModel

import spacy
```

`nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")`

### Error:-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8bdf9ac04f54> in <module>
      1 # Initialize SpaCy model
----> 2 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
     49     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     50     """
---> 51     return util.load_model(
     52         name, vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config
     53     )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    418             return get_lang_class(name.replace("blank:", ""))()
    419         if is_package(name):  # installed as package
--> 420             return load_model_from_package(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    421         if Path(name).exists():  # path to model data directory
    422             return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_package(name, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    451     """
    452     cls = importlib.import_module(name)
--> 453     return cls.load(vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    454 
    455 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_md\__init__.py in load(**overrides)
      8 
      9 def load(**overrides):
---> 10     return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_init_py(init_file, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    613     if not model_path.exists():
    614         raise IOError(Errors.E052.format(path=data_path))
--> 615     return load_model_from_path(
    616         data_path,
    617         vocab=vocab,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_path(model_path, meta, vocab, disable, exclude, config)
    486     overrides = dict_to_dot(config)
    487     config = load_config(config_path, overrides=overrides)
--> 488     nlp = load_model_from_config(config, vocab=vocab, disable=disable, exclude=exclude)
    489     return nlp.from_disk(model_path, exclude=exclude, overrides=overrides)
    490 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model_from_config(config, vocab, disable, exclude, auto_fill, validate)
    523     # registry, including custom subclasses provided via entry points
    524     lang_cls = get_lang_class(nlp_config["lang"])
--> 525     nlp = lang_cls.from_config(
    526         config,
    527         vocab=vocab,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in from_config(cls, config, vocab, disable, exclude, meta, auto_fill, validate)
   1783                     # The pipe name (key in the config) here is the unique name
   1784                     # of the component, not necessarily the factory
-> 1785                     nlp.add_pipe(
   1786                         factory,
   1787                         name=pipe_name,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in add_pipe(self, factory_name, name, before, after, first, last, source, config, raw_config, validate)
    786                     lang_code=self.lang,
    787                 )
--> 788             pipe_component = self.create_pipe(
    789                 factory_name,
    790                 name=name,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in create_pipe(self, factory_name, name, config, raw_config, validate)
    669         # We're calling the internal _fill here to avoid constructing the
    670         # registered functions twice
--> 671         resolved = registry.resolve(cfg, validate=validate)
    672         filled = registry.fill({"cfg": cfg[factory_name]}, validate=validate)["cfg"]
    673         filled = Config(filled)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in resolve(cls, config, schema, overrides, validate)
    744         validate: bool = True,
    745     ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
--> 746         resolved, _ = cls._make(
    747             config, schema=schema, overrides=overrides, validate=validate, resolve=True
    748         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in _make(cls, config, schema, overrides, resolve, validate)
    793         if not is_interpolated:
    794             config = Config(orig_config).interpolate()
--> 795         filled, _, resolved = cls._fill(
    796             config, schema, validate=validate, overrides=overrides, resolve=resolve
    797         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in _fill(cls, config, schema, validate, resolve, parent, overrides)
    848                     schema.__fields__[key] = copy_model_field(field, Any)
    849                 promise_schema = cls.make_promise_schema(value, resolve=resolve)
--> 850                 filled[key], validation[v_key], final[key] = cls._fill(
    851                     value,
    852                     promise_schema,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in _fill(cls, config, schema, validate, resolve, parent, overrides)
    847                     field = schema.__fields__[key]
    848                     schema.__fields__[key] = copy_model_field(field, Any)
--> 849                 promise_schema = cls.make_promise_schema(value, resolve=resolve)
    850                 filled[key], validation[v_key], final[key] = cls._fill(
    851                     value,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in make_promise_schema(cls, obj, resolve)
   1055                 sig_args[name] = (annotation, default)
   1056         sig_args["__config__"] = _PromiseSchemaConfig
-> 1057         return create_model("ArgModel", **sig_args)
   1058 
   1059 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in pydantic.main.create_model()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\fields.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\fields.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\fields.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic\fields.cp38-win_amd64.pyd in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis()

~\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py in __subclasscheck__(self, cls)
    772         if self._special:
    773             if not isinstance(cls, _GenericAlias):
--> 774                 return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
    775             if cls._special:
    776                 return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)

**TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below to your requirements:

```
typing-inspect==0.8.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
```

*There appears to be a bug in Pydantic v1.10.7 and earlier related to the recent release of typing_extensions v4.6.0 that causes errors for import spacy and any other spacy commands for python 3.8 and python 3.9*

---

*For spacy v3.2 and v3.3, we have published patch releases with fixes for the typing_extension requirement. Upgrade to spacy v3.2.6+ or v3.3.3*

```
python -m pip install 'spacy~=3.2.6'
```

---

**Pydantic should be v1.10.8 or higher**

Here is the complete solution in this link:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/12659

Comment: Thank You so Talha Tayyab, your suggestion worked very well. Really appreciate your help