# Getting `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class` when trying to load `nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bc5cdr_md")`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I'm using spaCy to analyze a large set of medical text for commentary about diagnoses, which was working fine when I left it last week.

Now when I try to load the scispaCy library `en_ner_bc5cdr_md` I am getting the type error `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`

I used this exact library to analyze the same text last week and the only thing that has changed is that I've restarted my computer.

I'm running an anaconda distribution with python `3.8.8` on OSX `Version 13.5.2 (22G91)`

Any ideas what's going on?

This is the code, it never gets past importing the model.

```
import spacy
import scispacy
import pandas as pd

text = """The patient was diagnosed with pneumonia last year. He has a history of asthma and hypertension.  
His COPD symptoms have worsened over the last 2 months. The patient also suffers from migraines."""

nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bc5cdr_md") 

doc = nlp(text)

labels = []
counts = []

for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'DISEASE':
        if ent.text not in labels:
            labels.append(ent.text)
            counts.append(1)
        else:
            idx = labels.index(ent.text)
            counts[idx] += 1
            
df = pd.DataFrame({'Diagnosis': labels, 'Count': counts})
print(df)
```

If you are able to run on you machine please let me know the parameters. You will also need to run - `!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.4.0/en_ner_bc5cdr_md-0.4.0.tar.gz`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77037891/typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class)

Comment: I saw this already, unfortunately no. Thanks though!

Comment: Are you getting the error at `import scispacy` or at `nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bc5cdr_md")` ?

Comment: `nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bc5cdr_md")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to load `en_ner_bc5cdr_md` with `spacy == 3.0.9` and python `3.10.12`. You can try the following steps:

1. `!pip install spacy==3.0.9` ('!' is for notebook cell)
2. `!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.4.0/en_ner_bc5cdr_md-0.4.0.tar.gz`

And then try:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bc5cdr_md")
```

Sorry, currently I don't have any local machine but I tested it on google colab and it's working fine on my end.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. Did not fix it locally unfortunately but i hadn't thought to use google collab so was ablle to run the code which is the main thing.

Comment: Sure, glad to help!